# How to make an alias link to a Windows server folder

Tags: macos, finder, dock, alias

On our server (windows 2012) we have a folder for Scan files called server/scans/(username). I know how to setup link from windows PC so that user can access the scans. How do I setup the same thing on a Mac Pro notebook?

I understand Apple calls shortcuts as alias. Before I'd just start a shortcut and type in IP address to setup path. How do I do this on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

**Drag to the Dock or Sidebar**

- You can drag the Folder to your dock (between the trash and the separator to the applications), or to the sidebar in Finder.

**Create an Alias**

You can also create an Alias:

- Click the icon to select (highlight) it, and in the File Menu, choose "Make Alias".
- Drag the folder holding down both the 'Option' `⌥` and 'Command' `⌘` keys together while you release the mouse button (a small arrow will appear in the lower left of the icon).

An Alias, like a Windows shortcut, is an icon that can be placed in any folder or on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Finder Preferences then tick 'Connected Servers' under "Show these items on the desktop."

This worked for me.